# main method calling no-static method

Tags: java, methods, static

I have read that a static method can't call a no-static method, but this compile, the main(static) method call maybeNew(no-static) method, can you give me a clue?

```
public class Mix4 {

    int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0;
        Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
        int x = 0;
        while (x<9) {
            m4a[x] = new Mix4();
            m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter + 1;
            count = count + 1;
            count = count + m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
            x = x + 1;
        }

        System.out.println(count + " " + m4a[1].counter);
    }

    public int maybeNew(int index) {
        if (index<5) {
            Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
            m4.counter = m4.counter + 1;
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: "*but this compile*" - Because you create an instance of `Mix4`, on which you call the method. If you were to try to call `maybeNew(1);` as-is (i.e. without anything else prefixing it), you will [get a compiler error](https://ideone.com/FW8ytA).

Comment: You have created an instance of Mix4 which is a local variable. This is the traditional way to access non-static in a static method.
refer these for more information.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/index.htm

Comment: Thanks Turing85.

Comment: Thanks Asel Siriwardena

Comment: where did you read that? (it must be possible, otherwise never a non-static method would be run/called since all programs start from static `main`) BTW `println()` is also non-static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call a non-static method directly from a static method but you can always call a non-static method from a static method using an object of the class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // sayHello(); // Compilation error as you are calling the non-static method directly from a static method
        Main main = new Main();
        main.sayHello();// OK as you are calling the non-static method from a static method using the object of the class
    }

    void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```